# How change system font color Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: fonts, colors

I've been searching but i can't get a specific guide to changing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS' font color.

I am using the Dfcon editor to change the background and base color of the system, the code being:

```
bg_color:#202020;selected_bg_color:#00FF00;base_color:#white
```

But the desktop icon and GUI applications [are unreadable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDXRr.png):

[image]

So there is any easy way for Linux beginners to change this boring gray font?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme and, with it, change the font color.

For doing it, look for appearance in the dash and choose other theme from the list.

I know it's not the same, but is the only thing that I can think.